# How do I convert an array to an object with different keys on the first and last array elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects, reduce

This is what I have tried so far.

Which works except that I cannot figure out how to change the first and last date keys?

```js
 const dates: any = [
    '2020-06-24',
    '2020-06-25',
    '2020-06-26',
    '2020-06-27',
    '2020-06-28',
    '2020-06-29',
    '2020-06-30',
  ];

  const dateArrayToObject = () => {
    const dateObject = dates.reduce(
      (acc: string, date: string) =>
        Object.assign(acc, {
          [date]: { selected: true, marked: true },
        }),
      {}
    );

    return dateObject;
  };
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: the first  [date]: { startingDay: true, marked: true } and the last the first  [date]: { endingDay: true, marked: true },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you need.

```js
const dates = [
    '2020-06-24',
    '2020-06-25',
    '2020-06-26',
    '2020-06-27',
    '2020-06-28',
    '2020-06-29',
    '2020-06-30',
  ];

var res= dates.reduce((acc, v, index, arr)=>{
  if(index === 0){
    acc = [...acc, {[v] : {startingDay: true, marked: true}} ]
  }else if(index === arr.length-1){
    acc = [...acc, {[v] : {ending: true, marked: true}} ]
  }else{
    acc = [...acc, {[v] : {selected: true, marked: true}} ]
  }
  return acc
},[])
console.log(res)
```

UPDATE: if you want to keep the result as an object instead of an array, you can do this:

```js
 const dates = [
        '2020-06-24',
        '2020-06-25',
        '2020-06-26',
        '2020-06-27',
        '2020-06-28',
        '2020-06-29',
        '2020-06-30',
      ];

    var res= dates.reduce((acc, v, index, arr)=>{
     
           acc = index === 0? {...acc, ...{[v] : {startingDay: true, marked: true}} }
              : index === arr.length-1 ? acc = {...acc, ...{[v] : {ending: true, marked: true}} }
              : acc = {...acc, ...{[v] : {selected: true, marked: true}} }
      return acc
    },{})
    console.log(res)
```

Comment: Although I do need to keep it an object and not an array which is a slight issue

Comment: You can take {} instead of [] as `acc` and accordingly generate the code

Answer (score 1):

Use the third argument `i` (index) in reduce method.

```js
 const dates = [
    '2020-06-24',
    '2020-06-25',
    '2020-06-26',
    '2020-06-27',
    '2020-06-28',
    '2020-06-29',
    '2020-06-30',
  ];

  const dateArrayToObject = () => {
    const dateObject = dates.reduce(
      (acc, date, i) =>
        Object.assign(acc, {
          [date]: { selected: true, marked: true, 
            first: i === 0,
            last: i === dates.length - 1 
            },
        }),
      {}
    );

    return dateObject;
  };
  
  console.log(dateArrayToObject())
```

Answer (score 0):

using `map` operation you can transform each object  with few extra props e.g `firstElement` and `lastElement` and keeping rest of elements as it is returning with new Array of objects.

```
const dates = [
    '2020-06-24',
    '2020-06-25',
    '2020-06-26',
    '2020-06-27',
    '2020-06-28',
    '2020-06-29',
    '2020-06-30',
];

dates.map((value, index) => {
            const obj = {
                selected: true,
                marked: true
            };

            if (index == 0) {
                obj.firstElement = true;
                return obj;
            } 
            else if (index == dates.length - 1) {
                obj.lastElement = true;
                return obj;
            } 
            else {
                return obj;
            }
});
```